# FlywayDB and data replication

Tags: database-replication, flyway

`FlywayDB` documentation does not mention anything related to the use of this software together with data replication.

Can `FlywayDB` be used with `Oracle RAC` and `DB2 Q Replication` ? Are there any `FlywatDB` specific guidelines related to data replication available ?

Answer (score 0):

Data replication is related to each database engine itself.

FlywayDB focus is quite different. It's a solution that focus on database change management (DATA oriented, of course).

For instance, creating an schema using FlywayDB in an Oracle standalone database will be the same process as to create it in an ORACLE RAC database.